# Why Oracle similar queries generate explain plan very different

Tags: sql, oracle, explain

Why the following very similar queries produce very different plans?

Query 1

```
SELECT *
FROM ACTORREPORTADO_RIESGO ars1
WHERE ars1.fechariesgo =
            ( SELECT MAX(fechariesgo) FROM actorreportado_riesgo ars2
                WHERE ars2.idactorreportado=ars1.idactorreportado
            )
        AND COALESCE(nivelriesgo,' ') NOT IN ('N',' ')  this is the line diff
```

[image: Plan for Query 1]

Query 2

```
SELECT *
FROM ACTORREPORTADO_RIESGO ars1
WHERE ars1.fechariesgo =
            ( SELECT MAX(fechariesgo) FROM actorreportado_riesgo ars2
                WHERE ars2.idactorreportado=ars1.idactorreportado
            )
        AND nivelriesgo NOT IN ('N',' ');  -- this is the line diff
```

[image: Plan for Query 2]

The table has 15 rows

```
CREATE TABLE ACTORREPORTADO_RIESGO (
  IDACTORREPORTADO NUMBER(17) NOT NULL,
  FECHARIESGO DATE NOT NULL,
  NIVELRIESGO VARCHAR2(10),
  USUARIORIESGO VARCHAR2(50),
  OBSERVACIONES VARCHAR2(500),
  CONSTRAINT PK_ACTORREPORTADO_RIESGO PRIMARY KEY (IDACTORREPORTADO, FECHARIESGO)
)
```

Comment: The queries are logically equivalent. However, while that may be (should be!) obvious to a qualified programmer, it is not obvious to the optimizer. The optimizer would have to analyze the second argument to `coalesce`, notice that it is a literal, then inspect the values in the `NOT IN` list and notice that the same literal appears in the list, and therefore the first query can be transformed into the second, with a cheaper plan. That is asking too much of the optimizer. Best if we write the simpler - more efficient - query ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `COALESCE(nivelriesgo,' ')` is an expression that must be evaluated for every row, so the db can't use indexes (if they exist) on `nivelriesgo` or use the `nivelriesgo` value straight from the table.

I expect you would get both plans the same if you changed it to the logically equivalent:

```
AND nivelriesgo IS NOT NULL
AND nivelriesgo NOT IN ('N',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

tldr; the optimizer has no idea what `COALESCE(nivelriesgo,' ')` is so won't do great.

The nitty gritty:
The most important thing here is cardinality and how Oracle is able to estimate it.

```
COALESCE(nivelriesgo,' ') NOT IN ('N',' ')
```

Oracle has no idea about the distribution of the expression `COALESCE(nivelriesgo,' ')` so it has to fall back on some hard coded guesses. For each element in the `NOT IN` list, Oracle will use apply 5% selectivity. So two elements gives you 5% AND 5% (as the value of the expression must be not 'N' and not ' ') which gives you a selectivity of 0.25%. Applied to your base cardinality of 15: Oracle estimates this filter (on it's own) will give you 1 row (rounded up from 0.0375).

If Oracle believes that applying the filter with a table scan will return one row then it will believe that it only has to run the scalar correlated subquery once. This seems quite cheap to the optimizer because there is a supporting index for this correlated subquery.

When you change the outside filter to

```
nivelriesgo NOT IN ('N',' ')
```

Oracle all of a sudden has some information to base this estimation on - it knows how many different values of `nivelriesgo` you have in your table (thanks to the statistics), it knows what the range of those values are, it might even have an idea of the distribution (if you have a histogram).
According to your plan, Oracle estimates this filter will return 14 rows (out of 15). Looping the scalar correlated subquery 14 times is obviously less appealing than just the once so it's not such an obviously good idea.

It has determined that it can rewrite your query so that it is effectively

```
select ars1.*
from  ( select ars2.idactorreportado
              ,max(fechariesgo) max_fechariesgo 
        from   actorreportado_riesgo ars2
        group by ars2.idactorreportado
      ) ars2
join  actorreportado_riesgo ars1
  on  ars2.idactorreportado = ars1.idactorreportado
 and  ars2.max_fechariesgo  = ars1.fechariesgo
where ars1.nivelriesgo NOT IN ('N',' ');
```

So instead of having to execute that scalar correlated subquery once per row it identifies with your other filter, it has unnested it and will be able to do some work just once.

Now, this is where the super fun stuff comes in, Oracle isn't 100% confident about how many rows this new subquery will return. If there's a small number of results, it will use an index lookup (using the primary key) and keep the row if it matches on your `nivelriesgo` filter (which it believes will be true for most rows). If there's a large number of results from the subquery, it will just to the full table scan (returning only rows that match your `nivelriesgo` filter) and hash join that with the subquery results - this is usually quite optimal for large result sets.